# Check if Selenium Hub/Node are running on a given port

Tags: java, selenium, port

I want to check whether Selenium Hub or Node is running on a particular port (ex:- 5555). I already have the code to check whether a particular port is free or not. But I am not sure how to find out the application using the port.

```
if (Port is free)
    i=1
else if (Port is used as Selenium Hub)
    i=2
else if (Port is used as Selenium Node)
    i=3
else if (Port is used by apps other than Selenium)
    i=4
else
    i=5
```

Please let me know if this can be done using java.

Comment: do you mean 'is it the hub running on the port, or is it the node?' or do you mean 'does either of the hub or node run on this port'?

Comment: Is it the hub running on the port, or is it the node, or any other application or is it free? Based on the result I will be launching the Hub/Node in the port.

Comment: Are you running on windows or linux?

Comment: Running on Windows 7, Selenium Standalone version: 2.31.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to access a know http url to the node/server, if it responds with a non error (lets sey an 200 OK) you can assume it's a selenium running there, for example do a httpclient get to:

```
http://<host>:<port>/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html
```

If it does a 404 it's not selenium.